# How to Redirect Users to the Login Page when Trying to Access an Unpublished Content Page in Drupal 7

Tags: authentication, redirect, drupal-7

I am trying to have users accessing some draft content (unpublished contents) links so they can log in and get redirected to these links. Once they click on the link, they will get redirected to the login page and once they log in with their credentials they will get redirected to the desired page. What happens is that when they click on any links they get redirected to the homepage. 
I tried to add a rule in the /admin/config/workflow/rules but I was unable to figure out the conditions and actions of the proper event I need to add in order to have my users get redirected to login and then straight to the desired page (either published or unpublished it doesn't matter).
I am using Drupal 7.67 and mostly UI interface on a Windows 10 machine.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I can think of is create function like this.

```
function modulename_redirect_when_unpublished(){
  //Check if user is in rigth place (viewing nodes).
  if(arg(0) == 'node' && arg(1)){
    //Load this node.
    $node = node_load(arg(1));
    //Check if node status is different than published, and if user is not logged.
    if($node->status != 1 && !user_is_logged_in()){
      //Prepare destination to come back.
      $destination = arg(0) . '/' . arg(1);
      //Go to login page with destination saved.
      drupal_goto('user/login', array('query' => array('destination' => $destination )));
    }
  }
}
```

You can pass any path in "destination" parameter in GET and after login it will redirect you there.

Only question is where to put this function. For tests purpose I called it in one of my custom module `hook_init`, but you can put it somewhere else, just be sure it will be called on `'node/%'` pages - you mentioned something about using Rules, it could be done that way but I think it's overcomplicated to create custom rule just for one case to fire this particular function, so I suggest you to put this code in some `hook_init` like I did.

I've tested it on Drupal 7.57.